# jaxb exclude fields from upper class

Tags: xml, jaxb, jna

I have a static class thats extends Struture (JNA). There I have some fields (only integer). I can handle that class with jaxb, but when I serialize an object of that class, I have the field autoRead/autoWrite in the xml file. How can I exclude that fields from the xml?

I have set XmlAccessorType to None/property but everywhere the same.

my code:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
@XmlType(name = "Data", propOrder = { "field1", "field2", "field3", "field4", "field5" })
public static class Data extends Structure {
    public transient int type;
    @XmlElement(name = "field1")
    public int field1;
    @XmlElement(name = "field2")
    public int field2;
    @XmlElement(name = "field3")
    public int field3;
    @XmlElement(name = "field4")
    public int field4;
    @XmlElement(name = "field5")
    public int field5;

    @Override
    protected List<String> getFieldOrder() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return Arrays.asList(new String[] { "type", "field1", "field2", "field3", "field4", "field5" });
    }
```

Greets

Benjamin

Comment: Please post the code you have.

Comment: ok have edit the post....